# How to avoid returning null value (which should be default result) during iteration of a list?

Tags: java, null, default

I would like to have a method that **iterate** through a loop and if some condition is met then return a value (`"1"` in this case). The default value if condition is not true would be null. Is that fine to return `null` in such situation? What would be the cleanest solution to do that?

```
for (Obj1 obj1 : objects1) {
    for (Obj2 obj2 : objects2) {
        if (...) {
          return "1";
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you do with the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kepotx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917656/3625488) is one good way (returning true or false):

```
boolean b = containsOne();
if (b) {
    // Do something with success...
} else {
    // Do something with failure...
}

private boolean containsOne() {
    for (Obj1 obj1 : objects1) {
        for (Obj2 obj2 : objects2) {
            if (...) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

However another way you could do this is with a [try and catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) which is mentioned in [Clean Code](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882):

```
try {
    int i = getOne();
    // Do something with success...
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do something with failure...
}

private int getOne() throws Exception {
    for (Obj1 obj1 : objects1) {
        for (Obj2 obj2 : objects2) {
            if (...){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if there is only two possibility (1 or null in your case), the best way is to return a `boolean`

```
for (Obj1 obj1 : objects1) {
      for (Obj2 obj2 : objects2) {
        if (...) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to not return null if the caller expect something from your method.

- For example if your method is supposed to return a String, when
  nothing is found just return an empty String `""`
- Or if your function is supposed to return a number of something,
  return a invalid number `-1`
- If the method is supposed to return a list of something, return an
  empty list.

When you don't have a something that could be interpreted as wrong value that can be returned. Then return null

---

In every case it's your responsibility to write documentation that explain what is return in this case. And it's the responsibility of the caller to check if the returned object is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution to counter the null pointer is to use Optionals that's introduced in JDK8. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Optional introduced in java 8

[browse here](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-optional-in-depth/)